# Locator not working for framework when provide CLICK ELEMENT href="#/triage/new"

Tags: robotframework

As part implementation of robotic framework, we have a page with locator `href="#/triage/new`. I tried using `href="#/triage/new"` but I get error "Locator not found". What do I need to use instead?

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: `href=...` is not a valid locator. Please show an actual test case so we can see how you're actually using that locator.

Comment: Open Browser        ${URL}    ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window
    INPUT TEXT  ${ID}         TESTUSER01
    INPUT TEXT  ${password}   ${pwd}
    CLICK ELEMENT  ${Signin}
    CLICK ELEMENT   ${SiteDrodown}
     Select From List By Index    //*[@id="SiteRoleSelectionListId"]    3
    CLICK ELEMENT   ${Sitesignin}
    click link  href="#/triage/new"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...I only have href value which is "#/triage/new" ,which opens up another page of the applictaion when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the locator type as href (`href=`), but I don't think that is a supported explicit strategy (e.g. needed to be specified). If you look at the list of the [baked-in ones](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Locating%20elements), it's not there; and checking the "Default locator strategy" subsection, you can see it says href is an implicit strategy for `Click Element`.
E.g. drop the `href=` prefix from the locator's value.

There is another thing, the quotes you've put in the value - you don't need them. In fact, they are harmful - the SeleniumLibrary treats them as part of the value itself, and looks for an element with href that has a quote in it. Drop them too :)